# Strange behavior of 'qgis:joinattributesbylocation' in PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis

Now, I'm trying the `qgis:joinattributesbylocation` in PyQGIS and I'm just facing the problem. Like the figure, I have two polygons and one is the plant community polygon (Figure1) and the other is the polygon which display the area range (Figure2).

After splitting the plant community polygon with the lines of area range polygon,  I conducted the `qgis:joinattributesbylocation` and wanted to assign the area range information (like 45, 46, 47 in figure).

Area range information were provided to some parts of the polygon  without any problems (pink color polygons in figure1), however, some of the polygons were failed to assign the area range information.

Why these problem was happened and any solutions?

[image: Figure1]

[image]